# Automatic scrolling in a PDF using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a newbie to iOS and just recently finished the Swift developer tutorial on the Apple website. I want to create a program that loads in a PDF that can automatically scroll, like a teleprompter. I was looking through the PDFView documentation, but could not find a scrolling function. The closest things I could find were [go](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/1505028-go) but I don't understand what it means by rectangle and [scrollSelectionToVisible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/1504529-scrollselectiontovisible) which I'm not quite sure what it does. Any help / tips / general Swift knowledge would be appreciated! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to switch to vertical scrolling is to start all the way from scratch at CGContextDrawPDFPage

If the selection is not visible, scrolls view so that it is.
You can put pdfview on the top of UIScrollView and then give a timer to let it auto scroll like PDFExpert.
You can visit the demo from Apple.

Visit here[ZoomPDF](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Listings/ZoomingPDFViewerSwift_ZoomingPDFViewer_TiledPDFScrollView_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281-ZoomingPDFViewerSwift_ZoomingPDFViewer_TiledPDFScrollView_swift-DontLinkElementID_26)

It needs time to make it happen, nobody can tell you how to make it happen quickly , based on my experience it's the core code about PDF application such as PDFExport, but the mind is same, you can do as I said.The PDF inherits  to UIView, so you should know why it can support auto scroll. Chose UIScrollView , it's right choice.